# No sound on my 21.5inch, mid2011 imac bootcamp running windows10

Tags: bootcamp, audio, imac, windows

after installing windows10 (upgrade win7) on my 21.5 inch mid 2011 imac for the first time everything was ok (including sounds),
after losing my system and have to re-install directly windows 10 ISO file, everything went ok except for no sound,
i tried almost everything over days, that included re-install bootcamp 5.1.5 (same i used before), then downloaded windows support software from bootcamp assisstant on my 10.9.5 OSX, many cirrus drivers (and realtek), windows troubleshooter, device manager, etc .. still no sound.
btw, i tried apple and windows support with no solutions!

Comment: Search on here, this has been asked before, see this for one : https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/231249/237687

Comment: And here : https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/328331/237687